# UISearchBar in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I am wondering to programmatically put a `UISearchBar` into `UINavigationController`, rather than replacing `UINavBar` title, as **I want the large title to show up**. See Files app on iOS.

[image]

**Here is my `.swift`**

`class Search: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar()
}

func searchBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "search".localized
    navigationItem.searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

The point is: by changing `nil` to actual `searchResultsController`, after typing text into search bar, the whole navigation controller (with search bar and typed text) got replaced by the `searchResultsController` view. **No search bar while typing into it in short.**

I am trying hard to use iOS 11/12 native look and feel within the app and putting the search bar into `TableViewController` is a no way here. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you need a different view controller to display the results ? This is what you do when to change nil to searchResultsController, I find this weird that you update this, generally you initialize the UISearchController directly with the view controller that you want (here your searchResultsController and not nil then the view controller).

Comment: @adrgrondin I dont need a different view controller. I am just lost while I was using the search bar from storyboard, usually. If you can make this an actual answer, would be nice, tbh :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok I will post an answer to try to explain you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a different view controller to display the results simply use (it will not make your navigation bar disappear):

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

And do not change the value after that.

Most of your code is good, however you will need to implement the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol to detect updates (when the user write in the search bar) and use a table view (inside your view controller) to display the results of the search.
You do that by reloading the data of your table view inside the function: updateSearchResults(for searchController:) after filtering the data you want with the text inside the search bar. You can read this good [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) on the subject for more information.

Comment: I am booting, will let you know in next 5 minutes.

Comment: Good luck on that!

Comment: Worked. Your tutorial helped me a lot, indeed :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Good luck with your project and iOS development!